# MediaRecorder - How to "clear" blob data/create new recording?

Tags: cordova, audio, phonegap, mediarecorder, recording

I'm using the Phonegap MediaRecorder to record some audio on IOS. There's a record, stop record and play button. It works fine, except when I hit record/stop again to try to do another recording, it still plays the first recording I've made.

How do I overwrite the previous recording everytime I hit the record button, or "clear" the blob data? Thanks.

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("device ready to go.");
    console.log(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia);
}



navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    'audio': true
}).then(function(mediastream) {
    var options = { mimeType : 'audio/wav'};
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediastream, options);

//start recording

Appery("RecordAudioButton").click(function() {
               mediaRecorder.start();
        console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
               console.log("recorder started");

           });

//stop recording

Appery("StopRecord").click(function() {
              mediaRecorder.stop();
          console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
               console.log("recorder stopped");

           });

//play recording

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(blob) {
    var audioURL = mediaRecorder.src;
    if(device.platform === 'iOS') {                 // iOS ; cordova-plugin-device required for this check
        Appery("audioPlayer").attr("src", audioURL);
    } else {
        var recordedChunks = [];
        recordedChunks.push(blob.data);
        audioURL.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(recordedChunks));   // Android device
    }
};


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting audioURL.src to null in the beginning of your ondataavailable function